# Is there a way of combining bash scripts?

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra

I am using chef to write a recipe that installs mysql connector, extracts it and moves the .jar to the /lib folder.

```
bash "install_mysql-connector" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/opt/tomcat/lib/"
  code <<-EOH
    wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.tar.gz
    tar -zxvf mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.tar.gz
  EOH
end

bash "setting_mysql-connector" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/opt/tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29"
  code <<-EOH
  mv mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar /opt/tomcat/lib/
  rm -rf mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.tar.gz
  EOH
 end
```

Is there a way of combining these two so they run under the same bash?

I also tried extracting JUST the mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar from the tar.gz file using

```
tar -zxvf mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat/lib mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar
```

Is something missing from this?

Comment: Please don't use `wget`. That's dumb. Use `remote_file` to download files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Extract the jar file out of .tar.gz and save under /opt/tomcat/lib directly?

```
tar -zxvf mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.tar.gz mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar -O > /opt/tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar
```